# Find 0,1-variables in DF and set as factor with level order

Tags: r

I want to find 0,1 variables and set them to factor with level order c(1,0). What is the fastest way of doing so.

### Data:

```
ds <- mtcars[,c(2,8:11)]

                    cyl carb vs am gear
Mazda RX4             6    4  0  1    4
Mazda RX4 Wag         6    4  0  1    4
Datsun 710            4    1  1  1    4
Hornet 4 Drive        6    1  1  0    3
Hornet Sportabout     8    2  0  0    3
...
```

Obviously, rule needs to be applied to `vs` and `am`. Is there a quick way without going all too tangled?

rule: `factor(., levels = c(1,0))`

#### Current solution:

```
DummyNames <- names(ds)[sapply(ds,function(x){x %>% na.omit %>% unique %in% c(0,1) %>% all})]
ds[,DummyNames] <- lapply(ds[,DummyNames],factor,levels=c(1,0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea that finds the columns with `c(1, 0)` by `colSum`. If the `colSum` of x == 1 or x == 0 equals the number of rows of the data frame, it means that all values are either 0 or 1. You can do this in one line, i.e.

```
ds[colSums(ds == 1 | ds == 0) == nrow(ds)] <- 
            lapply(ds[colSums(ds == 1 | ds == 0) == nrow(ds)], factor, levels = c(1, 0))

#or in two lines
#i1 <- colSums(ds == 1 | ds == 0) == nrow(ds)
#ds[i1] <- lapply(ds[i1], factor, levels = c(1, 0))

#str(ds)
#'data.frame':  32 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# $ vs  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
# $ am  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

**UPDATE**: If you have `NA` values that you also need to capture in your pattern (as per @Benjamin's comment), then you should add it in your `colSums`, i.e.

```
colSums(ds == 1 | ds == 0 | is.na(ds))
```

Comment: missing values will result in an `undefined columns selected` error.  If you are willing at accept missing value, you can use `ds == 1 | ds == 0 | is.na(ds)`. If you don't want to accept columns with missing values, you'll need some other form of protection against them.

Comment: I was just thinking the same @Benjamin. Nice fix. Should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

One option below (modeled on `redcapAPI::recodeCheck`).

You should be careful with this, however, as it it rather greedy.  If it finds columns where all of the values are in `old`, it will convert it. I can envision variables with overlapping subsets where this would be appropriate.

The function works in two parts.  First, if you aren't sure what variables match your format, it will search the data frame for you.  After finding them, it will perform the conversions.

```
recodeValue <- function(df, vars, old = 0:1, new = c("No", "Yes"),
                        use_na = TRUE){
  # If no vars, search the data frame for variables consistent with `old`
  if (missing(vars)){
    vars = vapply(df,
                  function(x) all(x %in% if (use_na) c(old, NA) else old),
                  logical(1))
  }

  # Perform conversions
  if (length(vars)){
    df[vars] <-
      lapply(df[vars],
             function(x){
               factor(x, levels = old, labels = new)
             })
  }

  df
}

recodeValue(mtcars, old = 0:1, new = c("No", "Yes"))
```